# How to have relate two collections that have a one-to-one relationship

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 0 experience with NoSQL databases and it is hard to not come up with a "SQL solution" to this problem. I have a Restaurant, which obviously has an address. My first idea was to simply put a lot of fields such as country, city, zip, line1, etc... However I thought that referencing it to an Address document, giving me the flexibility to easily change the structure of Addresses, so after a little bit of research I came up with this:

```
var RestaurantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Address',
        required: true
    },
    // a few more fields
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
});

var AddressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    restaurant: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Restaurant'
    },
    line1: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    line2: {
        type: String,
    }
    // etc
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
});
```

My question comes after wondering how I would do if I wanted to retrieve all restaurants from a city, for example, I'd do something like find('Houston') and then get each Restaurant from each id referenced by the Addresses retrieved?

I feel like there's a better way to do this but at the moment I don't even know what else to search trying to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your address schema like this

```
var AddressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    restaurant: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Restaurant'
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    line1: {
        type: String,
    }
    // etc
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
});
```

Ques: how I would do if I wanted to retrieve all restaurants from a city?

Ans:  For this you can use populate of moongose

Ex:

```
var addressModule=require('addressSchema')
addressModule.find({city:'Houston'}).populate({'path':'restaurant','model':'restaurantSchema'})
```

Result:

```
[
{
  restaurant:{
      name:"ABC",
      address:"123"
     },
  city:"Houston",
  line1:"xxx"
},
{
  restaurant:{
      name:"DEF",
      address:"233"
     },
  city:"Houston",
  line1:"xxx"
}
]
```